# Did Goku get a Zenkai boost when Freezer gave energy to him?

Tags: dragon-ball-series, dragon-ball-super

We know Goku and Vegeta get energy when they are healed by senzu beans, regeneration chambers, Dende and they get Zenkai boosts. But what about when he gets energy from another warrior, like he got from Freezer? I remember Kibito healed warriors with his technique, wasn't his technique about giving energy?

Answer (score 1):

Frieza giving energy to Goku has nothing to do with Goku getting a Zenkai boost. Getting beaten up by Jiren indeed gave Goku a Zenkai Boost. The getting energy/ Recovering bit isn't essentially required to get a Zenkai boost. These are boosts which Saiyans get after recovering from severe injuries and near death experiences. The healing factor is just something logical that follows.